# How to hide object but keep shadow in EEVEE?

Tags: rendering, shadows, eevee-render-engine

This is very easy to do in Cycles, just have to click on the camera checkbox.

[image]

I cant figure out how to do this in EEVEE.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

EEVEE now [supports *some* Light Paths](https://developer.blender.org/rBS4f114419137e76acde2d60d256d470c5a7a4232b) but not all seems to be supported yet, or in working order.

Until then, use this workaround.

1. Add a *Transparent* shader to the object's material.
2. Under the material options set the *Blend Mode* to anything other
   than *Opaque*, most options seem to work.
3. Then under *Transparent Shadows* set it to opaque.

[image]

Comment: Well Damn, I did all of that but didn't notice the transparent shadows box appear. I thank you kindly as always. If you are ever in Southern California, I owe you a beer for all the times you have helped me.