# How to Get only Shadows from a Collection in 2.8 EEVEE?

Tags: shadows, eevee-render-engine, collections

I want to know is there a way to render Shadows only in Blender's new EEVEE Render Engine.
I want my objects in a separate collection and a ground plane on a separate collection(to receive shadows from the objects collection).I want to render the shadows only and not the objects.

Comment: Can you put a higher size pic ,its hard to see the nodes detail.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know Collection won't behave like Render Layers in Cycles but you can use material as below to hide your mesh and show only shadows in EEVEE.

[image: setup]

Comment: Similar to this right? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/122830/how-to-hide-object-but-keep-shadow-in-eevee

Comment: Yeah that is close but when I said only shadow it mean only shadow.
I don't even want to render the plane,

Answer (score 1):

[image: Shadow only]

Create some render layers.
Subtract shadow from alpha.
Play with it.